# Elasticsearch significant terms aggregation doc_count differs from hits when doing a match phrase search for the same term

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase, significant-terms

I am using the significant terms aggregation, which gives me n significant terms with their doc_count and bg_count using the following query:

```
{
  "query" : {
      "terms" : {"user_id": ["x"]}
  },
  "aggregations" : {
      "word_cloud" : {
          "significant_terms": { 
              "field" : "transcript.results.alternatives.words.word.keyword",
              "size": 200
          }
      }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

If I am taking a term returned by significant terms aggregation and do a match phrase query for that term. Then I am getting a different value of hits than the doc_count in the aggregation.

Match phrase query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "preprocess_data.results.alternatives.transcript": "<term>"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "user_id": "x"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 22
}
```

The field `preprocess_data.results.alternatives.transcript` has the following mapping:

```
{
    "type" : "text",
    "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "ignore_above" : 256
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to explain the difference in document count when doing an aggregation and a match phrase search. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is because the data regarding `doc_count` is fetched from all shards of your index, and this data could be approximate in case of significant terms aggregation. Quoting elastic search [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-significantterms-aggregation.html#_approximate_counts):

> The counts of how many documents contain a term provided in results
> are based on summing the samples returned from each shard and as such
> may be:
>
> - low if certain shards did not provide figures for a given term in their top sample
> - high when considering the background frequency as it may count occurrences found in deleted documents
>
> Like most design decisions, this is the basis of a trade-off in which
> we have chosen to provide fast performance at the cost of some
> (typically small) inaccuracies. However, the size and shard size
> settings covered in the next section provide tools to help control the
> accuracy levels